# Nest.Search<T> How do I get the field value for a short using Hits.Fields.FieldValue<object,short>

Tags: c#, nest

I'm attempting to return only the required fields during use of `Search<T>` which returns `ISearchResponse<T>`

I am specifying the fields to bring back e.g Fields("abspath","URLLen") and these are indeed brought back in the responses' Hits object.

Note:Page is my DTO and contains public properties for abspath (string) & URLLen(short).

The documented method to get a field that contains a string works fine:

```
var abspath = Hits.Fields.FieldValue<Page, string>(f => f.abspath)[0]
```

but trying to do this with short or int or long fails with null exception (since URLLen is null):

```
var length= Hits.Fields.FieldValue<Page, short>(f => f.URLLen)[0]
```

So am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

It fails because during the expression resolution (f=>f.URLLen) the Resolve(...) method
camel cases the response so fails.

Sure enough downloading the source code from github and adding in a unit test confirms this.
Changing the es object field name to 'uRLLen' fixes the problem.
Problem code area is

```
public string Resolve(MemberInfo info)
        {
            if (info == null)
                return null;

            var name = info.Name;
            **var resolvedName = name.ToCamelCase();**
            var att = ElasticAttributes.Property(info);
            if (att != null && !att.Name.IsNullOrEmpty())
                resolvedName = att.Name;

            return resolvedName;
        }
```

**This is by design - see http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/lowercase-property-names-from-NET-using-NEST-td4039978.html** for the quick fix. Also see
http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/index-type-inference.html